# Looking up WordPress account information from Host or php files

Tags: login, blog

I recently started working at a company where they would like their webpage to be updated. Unfortuantely, I only have the hosting information and the files that are associated with the FTP manager. The webpage loads and is running, but no one knows the WordPress account that it is linked to. The one they thought it was is not the the right one.

It is for this website, http://adventcapitalpartners.com. Their company has a lot of email addresses, and I have tried entering a few different ones into Wordpress to see if they could recover the username/password without any luck.

They use a theme purchased from ProPhotoBlogs.com and I do have all the coding files there. Is there a way that I can look up the username or email through the coding files? Or even the MySQL files?

Kind of desperate for some ideas here, as nothing seems to be working! lol

Answer (score 1):

You want to create your *own* admin username/password. This way, you leave their logins untouched *and* you'll have your own account, tied to your own email address.

To do this, you'll need to add 3 records in the database. The three entries you make are:

- A row in the **wp_users** table, which will be the details for the new admin account. (username, MD5 password, email, etc...)
- Two rows in the **wp_usermeta** table, which assign the appropriate top level permissions to that new user's **user_id** using the meta_keys: `wp_capabilities` and `wp_user_level`. For full permissions, `wp_capabilities` should be set to `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}` and `wp_user_level` should be `10`.

See my article for a full tutorial with phpMyAdmin: [Add an Admin User To a WordPress Database](http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-a-wordpress-database/)

Comment: This WordPress Codex article on resetting your password my also be useful. It lists numerous ways to do so. http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password

Answer (score 0):

if you got the host details ...
you can check the email of the admin in the DB (Database) in the wp_users table..